# Eliminar filas que contengan una determinada palabra en R

Tags: r, dataframe

Muy buenas!
he estado horas con este problema y no puedo avanzar...
tengo un dataframe con datos extraídos de twitter desde la librería Rtweet en R, estoy limpiando columnas que me sirven y sacando aquellos tweets que contengan valores que no quiero (que no sean mi pais, que contengas x valor, etc)
el problema surge cuando quiero eliminar tweets spam desde la columna text que almacena la cadena de caracteres que conforman lo que el usuario escribió en el tweet. básicamente quiero emular el filtro que genera excel en una columna, cosa de que si la celda contiene X palabra elimine la fila entera.

pd: agrego el código con el que he limpiado y un screenshot del dataframe.

```
# dejo solo las columnas de mi interes
DF <- DF %>% select(user_id,created_at,screen_name,text,source,display_text_width,favorite_count,
  retweet_count,lang,place_url,place_name,place_full_name,country,country_code,bbox_coords,location)

# creamos una nueva columna con un id para la empresa a anlizar
DF <- DF %>% mutate(DF, empresa = "empresa")

# creamos un filtro para dejar unicamente los datos en español o que no están identificados
DF<-filter(D, DF$lang == 'es' | DF$lang == 'und')

# quitamos todos los paises que no son chile, dejamos aquellos que no están registrados
DF<-filter(DF, DF$country_code == 'CL' | is.na(DF$country_code))
```

[image: dataframe]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que se puede hacer es combinar `filter` con alguna función para encontrar textos en otros, por ejemplo `grepl()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(text=c('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 
                  'consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua')) %>% 
  filter(grepl("tempor", text, fixed = TRUE))
```

`grepl("tempor", text, fixed = TRUE)` retorna un vector de lógicos de la misma cantidad de filas, el `TRUE` indica que se ha encontrado el patrón en la cadena, finalmente `filter()` filtra los datos usando directamente eel vector de lógicos.

Answer (score 2):

Lo resolví con esta función, muchas gracias a los que respondieron.

```
DF <- DF %>% filter( !str_detect( text, "#KimHyunJoong"))
```

en donde DF es el dataframe, text es la variable que contiene el párrafo y la cadena de texto es aquel dato por el cual queremos filtrar.